# Adwaita Background Appears Much Darker in Reality

Tags: linux, arch-linux, cinnamon, wallpaper

I like the default Adwaita background that came with `cinnamon` installed on Arch linux. For some reason however this background is very dark, much darker than it appears in the settings for choosing background:

[image]

As I like to be able to view my backgound through my transparent terminal and just generally prefer a slightly happier look is there a way to fix this or a reason this is happening? I know I could always edit the image with something like GIMP increasing the brightness to counteract this effect, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I think it changes with the time of the day.

Comment: @muru Sometimes after a reboot it appears much brighter like normal. So I don't think so

Comment: Probably a bug, but that's how it is: https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-backgrounds/blob/master/backgrounds/adwaita-timed.xml.in

Comment: @muru Cool. Is there a way to turn off the time animation or is it just how it is?

Comment: You could set it to the morning image directly (probably something like: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/adwaita-morning.jpg'`).

Comment: @muru Thanks. Hope that works now. I'll for sure know after a couple of reboots.

Comment: For reference in `cinnamon` the command is `gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/background/gnome/adwaita-day.jpg`